# How to access elements of FirebaseListObservable from scripts

Tags: angularjs, list, firebase, angularfire2

I am working with Angular 2 (more precisely Ionic 2) and Firebase. I use angularfire2 to make them communicate.

While I can very easily go through all the elements of a `FirebaseListObservable` in a view (using the *pipe async* syntax), I cannot find a way of doing this from within my scripts.

I've been looking for a while and there are no examples which show this way of accessing the data; they all access it from the view part of the application.

How can I access the elements of `FirebaseListObservable` from within scripts?

Comment: Can you show an example of the pipe async? Sounds like you want to subscribe to an obversable

Comment: @gerdi,     proposition here would be a FirebaseListObservable in my model        
`<ion-item *ngFor="let prop of proposition | async">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure what you are asking but i use

```
getData(fbPath:string) {
   return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.af.database.list(fbPath).subscribe(res => resolve(res));
   })
}
```

In my firebase service. I can then use it in the component like so

```
this.api.getData('organisations').then(data => {
    console.log(data);
}
```

Comment: Ok so that seems to work (already thank you), but I still can't iterate over data with say a foreach.

Comment: To extend on what I just said the problem is that I don't know in advance the structure of the data(I mean I know it, but typescript does not, so I cannot access say data.$key or data.value.

Is there a way to define the type in advance?

Comment: you could create a `export class` with the properties and types and then assign the variable that will hold `data` to that class... maybe